# Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length when I tried to plot a continuous graph

Tags: r

I wanted to come out with a function returning the number of observation from a dataframe (allfil_data, having different values of x1 from range -1 to 1), by changing the values of a threshold (x1_th_adj).

The data frame is as below:

```
structure(list(x1 = c(-0.761194029850821, 0.236467236467132, 
0.0188679245282589, -0.518518518518598, 0.473684210526331, 0.284280936454798
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The codes are:

```
Summ_x1_th <- function(x1_th_adj){
  nrow(filter(allfil_data, abs(x1) >= x1_th_adj))
}

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))
Summ_x1_th <- function(x1_th_adj){
  nrow(filter(allfil_data, abs(x1) >= x1_th_adj))
}
p + stat_function(fun = Summ_x1_th) + xlim(0,0.1)
```

The error shows:

```
In abs(x1) >= x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

PS: It can be done easily by for-looping with maybe 1000 observations, but I would like to see if ggplot can accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: What is `alfil_data`.  Your example is not reproducible

Comment: it's a data frame having the different values of x1.

Comment: I guess you need to pass  `x1_th_adj` in the `Summ_x1_th`

Comment: Try by wrapping `Vectorize`

Comment: It works, by: ```p + stat_function(fun = Vectorize(Summ_x1_th)) + xlim(0,0.1)```, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Vectorize`

```
p + 
    stat_function(fun = Vectorize(Summ_x1_th)) + xlim(0,0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating vectors, you can see these warning messages if the two vectors are different in length.

For example

```
x =1:10
y =1:12
x+y 
[1] 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 12 14
Warning message:
In x+y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

In case of y =11:12, x = 1:2 is reused. 
So i recommend to check length of vectors. And set the long one to the smaller one, or make two vectors length divisible without remainder.